# How does gitlab eases the work of authorizing ssh key?

Tags: linux, git, github, ssh, gitlab

While using git, in order to authorize developers, we ask them provide their public ssh key and then mark them as authorized.

With gitlab, developer can save their ssh public key through the Account Interface. How is the authorizing part handled!?

Please reply at earliest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is managed through **[gitlab-shell](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell)**, which replaces [gitolite](http://gitolite.com/gitolite/) since [GitLab 5.0](http://blog.gitlab.org/gitlab-5-dot-0-has-been-released/).

The [`bin/install`](https://github.com/gitlabhq/gitlab-shell/blob/master/bin/install) script is invoked from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

It comes with a set of commands, including ones for ssh key management:

#### Keys:

> Add key

```
./bin/gitlab-keys add-key key-782 "ssh-rsa AAAAx321..."
```

> Remove key

```
./bin/gitlab-keys rm-key key-23 "ssh-rsa AAAAx321..."
```

> Remove all keys from authorized_keys file

```
./bin/gitlab-keys clear
```

Comment: hi VonC! You mentioned "The `bin/install` script is invoked from `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`. There is similar comment in `bin/gitlab-shell`. I am not able to understand how this 'invoking' thing is going on. When push or pull is being made, how does gitlab-shell know about it?